# MS DOS COMMAND using command prompt

Tags: cmd, operating-system

How can I change one directory to another?
by using cd right?

```
C:\Users\CHRISTINA>cd C:\
C:\>cd C:\users\CHRISTINA\desktop
```

is this right? after I do this. nothing changes in my drive.

Comment: Type `cd /?` (or `help cd`) at that command prompt and read the documentation.

Comment: Obviously, this is not doing what you intend to do otherwise you wouldn't be asking a question. What is it that you intend to do? Your commands will simply change your current or "logged" directory to `C:\users\CHRISTINA\desktop` (and the first line is redundant.)

Answer (score 1):

question is already answered see:
https://superuser.com/questions/135214/using-cd-command-in-windows-command-line-cant-navigate-to-d